# Finding average of selection and then assigning it to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to create some dynamic code that, at this point, will select a bunch of cells, move the selection over two columns, then find the average of that selection and send that value to a cell. This is what I have so far, I am getting stuck at averaging the selection I've made:

```
Sub StatMakersub(Rng1 As Range)

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Object
    Dim InQuestion As Range
    Dim SelAvg As Object

     'Check every cell in the range for matching criteria.
    For Each Cell In Rng1
        If Cell.Value = 2000 Then
            If MyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)
            Else
                Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Range(Cell.Address))
            End If
        End If
    Next
     'Select the new range of only matching criteria
MyRange.Select
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
Set InQuestion = Selection
Range("P2").Formula = "=Average(Selection)"
Range("Q2").Formula = "=STDDEVA(Selection)"

End Sub
```

I can't find much on the web about how to average range variables.

Comment: First thing I googled has your answer... http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/292819-average-range-cells-visual-basic-applications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the average of a selection in this way:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Average("Here you put your range")
```

The result is a value and not an object, so you should use a variable. Taking names from your case you should use it like this:

```
SelAvgResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(InQuestion)
```

I put another name for the variable, but you may still use SelAvg if you like. Just remind to define it as a variable (you may choose your desired format depending on the data size) instead of object if you do not need it anymore.

You may use then this variable for setting the value of your desired cell.

I have a last note: your code seems to replicate the already existing formula AVERAGEIF. If your criteria column is for instance column A and value you should use for calculating the average are in column C, You could directly set the value of the cell where you want the average like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A, "2000", C:C)
```

In this case you would avoid VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Sum worksheet function for calculating the sum of the range?

Xsum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(arrayX)

and dividing the Xsum value with the length of the array?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I should metion is that you do not need to select the range to work with it. You can use it directly and doing so will also improve how fast your code runs.

To insert your worksheet functions, use the Range.Address function to generate a cell reference to put into the formulas.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx